# "quasi-increasing" permutation of a number

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations

> Call a permutation $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ quasi-increasing if $a_k\le a_{k+1}+2$ for each $1\le k\le n-1$. For example, $54321$ and $14253$ are quasi-increasing permutations of the integers $1,2,3,4,5$, but $45123$ is not. Find the number of quasi-increasing permutations of the integers $1,2,\ldots,7$.

This is personally, a very difficult problem.

I don't understand how $54321, 14253$ are quasi-increasing?

Comment: $(5,4,3,2,1)=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$. Now double check that $a_k\leq a_{k+1}+2$. If you want a hint toward this problem, try recursion. Suppose you know the answer for $n$, then for $n+1$, think of how many ways you can wedge $n+1$ into the $n$ case.

Comment: @AlexR., absolutely no idea.

Comment: For example, $a_1=5$, $a_2=4$, and $5\leq 4+2$.

Answer (score 0):

$54321$ is quasi-increasing because no digit (starting at the second digit) is more than two bigger than the one immediately preceding it, i.e. $5\ge 4+2$, $4\ge 3+2$, $3\ge 2+2$, etc.

Now, to solve the original problem, note that $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, $a_3=6$, because all permutations of these digits are quasi-increasing. Now, suppose we know the value of $a_i$ for some $i\ge 3$, and we're trying to get the value of $a_{i+1}$. For each permutation of $1$, $2$, ..., $i$, we can insert the number $i+1$ right after $i$ (so that the difference between those two digits is $1$), right after $i-1$ (so that the difference between those two digits is $2$), or in the very beginning of the sequence. For each permutation of $1$, $2$, ..., $i$ there are three ways of inserting $i+1$, so $a_{i+1}=3a_i$ for all integers $i \ge 2$.

Therefore, the number of quasi-permutations of the integers $1$, $2$, ..., $n$ is
$$\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } n=1\\
2*3^{n-2} & \text{if } n \ge 2
\end{cases}
$$

Plugging in $n=7$, you get $2*3^{7-2}=486$.